# Как оптимизировать эту программу, ибо она не выводит ничего при таком большом промежутке, python

Tags: python, циклы, числа

Найдите все натуральные числа, принадлежащие отрезку [35 000 000; 40 000 000], у которых ровно пять различных нечётных делителей (количество чётных делителей может быть любым). В ответе перечислите найденные числа в порядке возрастания.
Вот такое вот задание должно решаться таким вот кодиком:

```
from math import sqrt

for i in range(35000000, 40000001):
    dels_count = 0
    for j in range(1, round(sqrt(i)) + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            if j % 2 != 0:
                dels_count += 1
            par_del = i / j
            if par_del % 2 != 0:
                dels_count += 1
    if dels_count == 5:
        print(i)
```

но ничего не вылезает, хотя с промежутками поменьше всё пашет

Comment: `j` в `range()` можно сразу с инкрементом 2 брать. Чтобы не проверять на чётность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Число 81 имеет ровно пять нечётных делителей. Я добавил в ваш код отладочную печать:

```
from math import sqrt

for i in range(81, 82):
    dels_count = 0
    for j in range(1, round(sqrt(i)) + 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            if j % 2 != 0:
                dels_count += 1
                print('found', i, j)
            par_del = i / j
            if par_del % 2 != 0:
                dels_count += 1
                print('found', i, par_del)
    if dels_count == 5:
        print(i)
```

> ```
> $ python five_odd_divisors.py 
> found 81 1
> found 81 81.0
> found 81 3
> found 81 27.0
> found 81 9
> found 81 9.0
> ```

Главная проблема: делитель `9` учтён два раза. Меньшая проблема: деление целых в Питоне производит вещественный результат.

Поправьте эти проблемы и ваш код заработает. Время работы будет около часа. Наберитесь терпения.